# How to prevent AWS RDS instances from changing AZs after Multi AZ true/false

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance that has a waiting required OS update, So I decided to open Multi AZ while applying the update. Update is finished, everything is fine, but I realized that AWS RDS instance is staying in us-east-1b, I was using us-east-1a. I closed the Multi AZ and configured DB as single AZ again, but my AZ config wasn't be applied back. it's still in us-east-1b. However,  most of my resources are in us-east-1a and I don't want to pay for extra inter-AZ networking cost.

Is there a workaround for this,

Any help will be highly appreciated,
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can create DB subnet zone in your preferred AZ, then create a snapshot of your database. From the snapshot you can restore a new database and assign the  create subnet group while restoring that database which will create your instance in AZ of your choice. Hope this resolves your issue!

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm managing database with Terraform, I'm afraid manuel-heavy resolutions will not be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

AWs doesn't give the option to choose in which zone to create seconday rds. If you can have a maintenace period of let's say 1 hour(depends on how big is the RDS), you can create the db from snapshot in the AZ of your choice but if it's not possible, the only option is to change to `MultiAZ` and hope the secondary DB is created in us-east-1a. Once you have it here, turn off `MultiAZ`.

Comment: I'm managing my RDS resource with Terraform, so creating DB from snapshot is not an option for me. Also I guess I need a pending maintenance or something has equal impact to make stand-by instance in us-east-1a take over the traffic. I tried reboot with failover but it didn't affect somehow. DB were rebooted but it's AZ didn't change.

Comment: @OguzhanAygun, are you sure the AZ didn't change? Sometimes, it does but console or even cli doesn't show you the new AZ immidiately. It's not certain that your standby will be in us-east-1a as there are 6 AZ in that region if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

1. Tur on multiAZ again
2. Restart database with force failover parameter.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RebootInstance.html
3. Turn off multiAZ

Comment: Hi I tried it, but it was not effective at all, my AZ didn't change with reboot with failover.